# What's the word that describes a person who thinks his/her mother tongue is superior to other languages ?

Tags: single-word-requests

A friend of mine keeps making nasty comments at people who are the same race as her and can't speak their mother tongue. Besides, she also believes some languages don't even matter. I'm looking for a word to call her the next time she does it

Comment: I've added the right tag here. Please take a moment to review the [tag info](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) and especially the check-list. I guess, since you use the word "nasty," that you don't agree with your friend, but some hints about what sort of word you require would be really useful. It may allow further tags to be added, such as [pejorative-language]. Note that this sort of question tends to engender heated responses and may get closed; that's why it helps to be as specific as possible.

Comment: You can share the same "race" (I'm guessing you meant ethnicity)  as another person, but if you were born in a different country your mother tongue, or first/native language, is the one you grew up speaking. So if your friend criticises a person whose physiognomy resembles her own culture and ethnicity for not speaking *her* mother tongue when that person was born and brought up in a different culture/country, she's not being very intelligent.

Comment: I think you can call her racist, nationalist, even language supremacist or fascist depending on context. There could be more.

Comment: The word is, *okay, bye now.*

Answer (score 5):

This is precisely called as "**Linguistic Chauvinism**"

Linguistic chauvinism is the idea that one's language is superior to others. For a few examples, the Greeks called all non-Greek speakers barbarians, the French are only at home where French is spoken, and English speakers consider the ability to speak another language a social defect

Source of above text: wiki answers

Comment: Really........?

Comment: Please [edit] to add citations to the source. I'm pretty sure these aren't your own words.

Answer (score 3):

One word for this is *parochial*. Your friend's view of things is limited to what s?he knows and is used to, which is apparently somewhat narrow.

Adjective: **parochial**  pu'row-kee-ul

1. Relating to or supported by or located in a parish

   "parochial schools"
2. Narrowly restricted in outlook or scope

   "little sympathy with parochial mentality";

   - insular

See also: provincial

-- [WordWeb Online](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=parochial)

Answer (score 2):

Bigot: A person who is intolerant towards those holding different opinions:

Chauvinist: A person displaying aggressive or exaggerated patriotism. Prejudiced against another's cause, group or sex.

Ethnocentric: Evaluating other cultures according to preconceptions originating in the standards and customs of one's own culture.

Xenophobic: Having or showing a dislike of or prejudice against people from other countries

Or simply Arrogant: Having or revealing an exaggerated sense of one's own importance or abilities.

All words that can refer to the ignorance/intolerance of another culture and it's tenets, whether that be language or something else.

(Definitions taken from www.en.oxforddictionaries.com)